# Tchat with NodeJS on port 1337 doesnt work (server on Debian)

Tags: node.js, ssl, port

Hello and sorry for my bad english, but I have a problem with my tchat created with NodeJS. My server.js running on port 1337 in my VPS, but with port isn't secure and i don't know how secure him.

All my website is secure with a Let's Encrypt certificate, but not the 1337 port...
I tried to secure https://www.temtem-france.com:1337/ with Let's encrypt but it doesn't work... :/

I have this on the beggining of my server.js :

```
var https = require('https'),
fs = require('fs'),
mysql = require('mysql');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/archive/temtem-france.com/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/archive/temtem-france.com/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/archive/temtem-france.com/chain.pem'),
  requestCert: false, rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  console.log('Affiché');
  res.end("Hello World\n");
}).listen(1337);
```

With inspector on my client.php code, i have this :

```
socket.io.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

client.js:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at client.js:31
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (client.js:117)
    at i (jquery-min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-min.js:2)

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

I already managed to run my codes, but it was several months ago and since I am not very comfortable with server management, I forgot how I had succeeded.

Thanks a lot if you can help me !